# Azure AD - Server side check if user logged in to the Azure AD using MSAL Angular

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I've managed to add Azure AD login to my angular application using MSAL Angular package.

I can simply use the following code in my `front end` login component (Typescript side) to check if the user has logged in,

```
const details = this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount();
if (details) {
   console.log('User has logged in.')
}
```

Now, I need to do the same on the `server side end` login controller (C#, .Net 6) and check if the user has logged in to the application using their Microsoft account.

So far I've tried to find a solution on the Microsoft documentation and their [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code),

Has anyone gone through this and found a solution?